# Median filter implementation testing

Tags: c, matlab, median

I implemented a 2D median filter in C. For an image of size 1440X1440, floating point values. For starting, I tried it with a simple 3X3 kernel size. Here's the code.

```
#define     kernelSize      3

void sort(float *array2sort, int n)
{
    float       temp;
    for(int i=0; i < n-1; i++)
        for(int j=0; j < n-1-i; j++)
            if(array2sort[j] > array2sort[j+1])
            {
                temp = array2sort[j];
                array2sort[j] = array2sort[j+1];
                array2sort[j+1] = temp;
            }
}


void medianFilter(float *input, float *output)
{
    int     halfKernelSize = kernelSize/2;

    float   neighbourhood[kernelSize*kernelSize];

    for(int i=0+halfKernelSize; i<(1440-halfKernelSize); i++)
        for(int j=0+halfKernelSize; j<(1440-halfKernelSize); j++)
        {
            for(int ii=-halfKernelSize; ii<halfKernelSize+1; ii++)
                for(int jj=-halfKernelSize; jj<halfKernelSize+1; jj++)
                    neighbourhood[(ii+halfKernelSize)*kernelSize+(jj+halfKernelSize)] = input[(i+ii)*1440+(j+jj)];
            sort(neighbourhood, kernelSize*kernelSize);
            output[(i)*1440+(j)] = neighbourhood[(kernelSize*kernelSize)/2+1];
        }

}
```

Now, in order to verify if the code is fine, I took an image, added salt & pepper noise to it using MATLAB. Then tried the above code on it. I can see the noise getting reduced ALMOST completely with a few dots remaining. If I increase the kernel size to 5X5, noise does get filtered completely. But the worrying fact for me is ,the MATLAB ,median filter code is able to remove the noise completely even with a kernel of size 3X3. That leaves me in doubt. Please have a look at the code and let me know if there is some fault in the filter implementation or the MATLAB code is taking some additional steps.

Comment: Now, in order to verify if the code is fine, I took an image, added salt & pepper noise to it using MATLAB. Then tried the above code on it. I can see the noise getting reduced ALMOST completely with a few dots remaining. If I increase the kernel size to 5X5, noise does get filtered completely. But the worrying fact for me is ,the MATLAB ,median filter code is able to remove the noise completely even with a kernel of size 3X3. Please have a look at the code and let me know if there is some fault in the filter implementation or the MATLAB code is taking some additional steps.

Comment: Don't add important information or what you have tried in comments, please *edit your question* instead.

Comment: That's what, I am wondering where is the option for editing the question.

Comment: Look just below the tags, there's line with links, one of them is "edit".

Comment: You could write/test 9 point median function first, and test against matlab's implementation again random input. Then move to median filter. I recommend mex files for this kind of development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the median value calculated from neighbourhood buffer is wrong.
It should have been neighbourhood[(kernelSize*kernelSize)/2].
Can you try with this correction?

Comment: for a 3X3 kernel, neighbourhood is an array of size 9(kernelSize*kernelSize). after sorting the median will be at index value of 5. which is = 9/2+1. (9/2 = 4). So, that oiece of code stands fine I think.

Comment: I agree that 5th value is the median. But in C, the array indexing start from 0. So if you want to access 5th element, you have to use array[4].

Comment: Thnx, that works great now. You pointed out the error correctly.